# Why is LaTeX3 method not working with token list argument, contrary to documentation?

Tags: latex3, strings, token-lists

I have the following code in which I try to check whether a letter exists in a string:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\begin{document}

\str_gset:Nn \ABCstring {ABC} % Setting the test string to 'ABC'

\tl_gset:Nn \my_tl {C} % Setting the token list to the single letter 'C'

C\ in\ ABC:~
\str_if_in:NnTF \ABCstring {C}{yes!}{no!}\\ % just the letter 'C'

\textbackslash my_tl(\my_tl)\ in\ ABC:~
\str_if_in:NnTF \ABCstring {\my_tl}{yes!}{no!}\\ % the letter 'C' from the tl

\end{document}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

It generates this output:

> C in ABC: yes!
>
> \my_tl(C) in ABC: no!

When I put just a `C` into the second argument of `\str_if_in:NnTF`, the code works as expected (yielding `yes!`), while the same character in a token list does not work.

The [LaTeX3 documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) gives the following signature:

```
\str_if_in:NnTF ⟨str var⟩ {⟨token list⟩} {⟨true code⟩} {⟨false code⟩}
```

accompanied with the following description:

> Converts the ⟨token list⟩ to a ⟨string⟩ and tests if that ⟨string⟩ is found in the content of the ⟨str var⟩.

From my understanding of the doc, both ifs above should yield `yes!` What is the problem?

I figured out that it works with

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_in:NnTF {NVTF}
```

but why is that necessary?

Comment: `\my_tl` is converted into the string `\ m y _ t l `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the documentation says, the second argument to `\str_if_in:NnTF` is  a `{⟨token list⟩}`. The token list you have passed is `\my_tl`, which is exactly one token. It is then detokenized as we are doing a string-based comparison, and we then have the string `\my_tl`, which comprises six 'other' tokens'. In contrast, you want to compare to the *content* of `\my_tl`, which is the single token `C` (catcode 11, 'letter'). This is passed when you use `V`-type expansion - it passes the *value* stored in `\my_tl`. And it it that you want to compare.